# Does each row in a silverlight dataGrid have to have the same "RowDetailsTemplate"?

Tags: silverlight

I'm defining a datagrid's RowDetailsTemplate in the following way:

RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}"

where

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="default" x:Name="_txt" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="otherTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="other" x:Name="_txt" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Is there a way to programatically define which of the two above DataTemplates a given row is to use (perhaps in the LoadingRowDetails() event)?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Would the data template change based on the data or some other external value?

Comment: I'd like to display a grid of items that are essentially the same, however drilldown data for each can be different eg: grid of employees with the RowDetails for each being dependent on their position.  The data template would therefore need to be changed based on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code in your LoadingRowDetails event, obviously replacing my useless If condition with your own:

```
    If 1 = 1 Then
        e.Row.DetailsTemplate = CType(Resources("defaultTemplate"), DataTemplate)
    Else
        e.Row.DetailsTemplate = CType(Resources("otherTemplate"), DataTemplate)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Thanks a lot Tom. It saved my day (week/month) :-)

And in C#:

```
if (1 == 1)
{
   e.Row.DetailsTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["defaultTemplate"];
}
else
{
   e.Row.DetailsTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["otherTemplate"];
}
```

To add more power to this solution the following 
msdn link shows how to create controls at runtime.